# How to use formControl with <td> tag in Angular2

Tags: angular

I'm trying to add formControl inside of table element, but I always get 
 `error:No value accessor for form control with name: 'sender'`. I tryto use formControl or formControlName but didn't work out. I say couple aritcles, it say use formControl with no tag, but it didn't work out

There is my code:

```
      <form [formGroup]="toolsubmitform">
      <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-5">
              <md-card class="user-card">
              <!-- <md-card-header>
                <img class="rounded-circle img-user" width="70" height="70" src="assets/img/SB-admin.png">
              </md-card-header> -->
                <md-card-title class="user-title">Stuff</md-card-title>
                <md-card-content>
                  <img class="rounded-circle img-user" width="100" height="100" src="assets/img/SB-admin.png">
                  <table class="table table-bordered">
                              <thead class="table-head">
                                  <tr>
                                      <th>staff Name</th>
                                  </tr>
                              </thead>
                              <tbody>
                                  <tr >
                                      <td><span formControlName='sender'>Jason</span></td>
                                      <td></td>
                                  </tr>
                              </tbody>
                          </table>
                </md-card-content>
            </md-card>
            </div>
         </form>
```

This is my components:

```
import { Component, OnInit,HostListener,NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {FormGroup, FormControl, Validators,FormArray,FormBuilder} from '@angular/forms';
import {HomepageService} from './homepage.services';
import {ToolUsing, Tool,Tooldetail} from './homepage.interface';

this.toolsubmitform=new FormGroup({
      'sender':new FormControl(),
      'operator':new FormControl(),
       tool:new FormArray([
        //  this.initTool(),
       ]),
    })
```

This is my version of angular2 :

```
"@angular/common": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/core": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/forms": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/http": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/router": "^3.3.1",
```

Comment: Is there any reason to not use `input`? `<td><input type="text" formControlName='sender' [ngModel]="'Jason'"></td>`.

Comment: I don't want to have the input box in the table, so I try to avoid use the input tag

Comment: What's the purpose?? I guess it can be used only in `input/select/textarea` tags (which makes a lot of sense to me)

Comment: Also, it seems like you want to set value of `sender` by default as *Jason*.. so, since it's not editable, you can put it directly in component `'sender':new FormControl('Jason')`. After did it you can remove the `formControlName` in *template*.

Comment: I won't set default value, I will render my data from backend api, Right now I just to do the test.